# What will happen to electronics devices if the AC mains power misses one full cycle of mains voltage?

Tags: ac, mains

What will happen to electronics devices if the AC mains power misses onr full cycle of mains voltage?

In a 50Hz mains country, you have 49 sine waves (cycles) and 1 period of zero/no voltage. What would happen to the AC powered devices?

Comment: This totally depends on which device(s) being discussed.  Please edit your question and name a device.

Comment: Depends on the device. Some will carry on without any impact, some will not work at all.

Comment: Some clocks were / are driven on the frequency so they will loose time  albeit slowly...

Comment: Depends on the product, but most needs to comply with IEC 61000-4-11, which requires minimum hold-up time for the type of events you describe. Can you narrow down which electronic devices you refer to?

Answer (score 2):

- Motors will continue to run due to inertia. There may be a current surge on reconnection of supply.
- Resistive devices such as heaters, incandescent lamps, etc., will switch off for that cycle. Usually thermal inertia will mean that you won't notice.
- Most electronic devices will be DC internally and will therefore have capacitors to maintain supply during mains zero-cross. During the missing cycle the capacitor voltage will droop more than normal. What happens then depends on the downstream circuit and how critical stable and correct voltage is to its operation.